# create canvas in a library on angular 6

Tags: angular, canvas

I'm trying to create a library on angular that would allow me to crop an image for that I would like use canvas.
I create a library with "ng generate library".
when I try to draw my canvas nothing appears.

crop-image.component.html :

```
<div class="container">
  <canvas #canvas [width]="width" [height]="height" >
hello
  </canvas>
  <div>
    <input type="file" accept="/image/*" (change)="onImageChange($event)">
  </div>
</div>
```

crop-image.component.ts :

```
import {Component, ElementRef, Input, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

// @ts-ignore
@Component({
  selector: 'lib-crop-image',
  templateUrl: './crop-image.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./crop-image.component.css']
})
export class CropImageComponent implements OnInit {


  imageUrl;
  @Input() width = 500;
  @Input() height = 500;
  @ViewChild('canvas') canvasRef: ElementRef;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const ctx = this.canvasRef.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(100, 100);
    ctx.stroke();
}
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `library`?

Comment: Do you want to display a selected image in `canvas`?

Comment: Please show the code which adds the `lib-crop-image` components to the HTML. Are you sure the component is found by Angular?

Comment: you can only use it in afterviewinit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following to get your canvas reference

```js
import {Component, ElementRef, Input, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

// @ts-ignore
@Component({
  selector: 'lib-crop-image',
  templateUrl: './crop-image.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./crop-image.component.css']
})
export class CropImageComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit  {


  imageUrl;
  @Input() width = 500;
  @Input() height = 500;
   @ViewChild('canvas') canvasRef: ElementRef;
  public context: CanvasRenderingContext2D;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.context = (<HTMLCanvasElement>this.canvasRef.nativeElement).getContext(
      '2d');
    this.context.moveTo(0, 0);
    this.context.lineTo(100, 100);
    this.context.stroke();
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ngOnInit() {
    const ctx = this.canvasRef.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(100, 100);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

should be

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
    const ctx = this.canvasRef.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(100, 100);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```